# Java XOR Custom Objects

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a custom class and I want to perform the XOR operation on its object.

Only way I can think of is to serialize object into String and then converting string into bytes array and then doing xor operation on each of its elements. Then, deserializing it when needed.

for example take simple case of List->

```
class ListNode {
   int val;
   ListNode next;
   ListNode(int val) {this.val = val;}
}

ListNode l1 = new ListNode(2);
ListNode l1 = new ListNode(3);

// ListNode x = l1 ^ l2;
```

I want to perform l1 XOR l2 for some efficient implementation but can't find a cleaner way to do it in Java.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
In one algorithm I have only 1 pointer but by using XOR representation I can use that to store 2 addresses.

Say, for example my list is 5->4->3->2->>>>>...
instead of storing next pointer of 5's node = 4; what I am trying to do is to store previousPointer XOR nextNodePointer in the next field of node.

So

```
5's next pointer = NULL XOR 4
4's next pointer = 5 XOR 3..........
```

So, in this case result of XOR should be saved.
One can now traverse like this we know null comes before head.
To access head's (5's) next node that is 4, we can perform null XOR nextPointer, so essentially we will do that for each node

```
5 next pointer = null XOR 4 as above/
to acess 4 do null XOR (null XOR 4) = 4
now to access 3 do 5 XOR (5 XOR 3) = 5...
```

So, I want to save this XOR information somewhere but I can't create one new list node to save it. 
Can this be done on address level somehow so that the results are consistent like in above operations.

Comment: What, to you, would it mean to XOR two object references?

Comment: You must define what you expect the XOR to do for your data structure. What is the expected result of I1 xor I2?

Comment: Out of interest why are you trying to do this?

Comment: What is your custom class, and how does it make sense to XOR it?

Comment: XOR operation defined on integer arguments. What you trying to do is like XOR two cats.

Comment: Edited the question to show some simple use case.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't support operator overloading, so you won't have `ListNode x = l1 ^ l2;`. Instead, you will have to define it as a method: `ListNode x = ListNode.xor(l1, l2);`.

In order to implement it, you could just iterate over the nodes:

```
public static ListNode xor(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode result = new ListNode(l1.val ^ l2.val);
    while (l1.next != null) {
        l1 = l1.next;
        l2 = l2.next;
        result.next = new ListNode(l1.val ^ l2.val);
    }
}
```

Note: This implementation assumes that `l1` and `l2` are the same length. If this assumption cannot be made, it should be tweeked as bit.

Comment: I was also thinking of doing this but this won't work for my case, as it won't fulfill XOR properties.
i.e. in your case result XOR l1 will not give l2 which is the property of XOR that  (l1 XOR l2) XOR l1 = l2;

Answer (score 1):

Serialazing two instances and xoring their representation as an array of bytes makes no sense(the result won't even be a valid representation of an instance of this class). If you want to xor specific fields of two intsances, well, just xor them.

Comment: I can't XOR specific fields like mentioned by @Mureinik  
In that case properties of XOR are not followed.
I want this property to hold (L1 XOR L2) XOR L1 = L2
where L1 and L2 are objects of custom class

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with references, because Java's garbage collector relies on being able to follow the references directly. You could probably get an integer version of the reference, but you wouldn't be able to go back from the integer to the reference, and if you don't store the reference to the node, the node will be garbage collected.

If you wanted, you could instead hold all the nodes in an array, and instead of each node having a reference to the prev/next node, it has the index of the prev/next node. That would allow you to do the XOR trick.

Comment: The reason why I was using this trick to do some algorithm in O(1) space, otherwise it was simple on its own using Hashtable in O(n) space.
Nonetheless, I think I may have to change the algorithm now. Anyways, thanks for your answer

Comment: @jalatif The XOR trick won't change the asymptotic space complexity of an algorithm, since it's just a constant-factor decrease.